# Deserialize query string to JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Tried to find how to make `{foo:"bar"}` from `?...&foo=bar&...` but googled and got only to `jQuery.params` which does the opposite. Any suggestions please (built-in javascript function, *jQuery*, *Underscore.js* - all goes)? Or, do I need to implement it by myself (not a big hassle, just trying not to reinvent the wheel)?

Comment: well here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript . A little search always helps.

Comment: @ggozad: searched for a *conversion into JSON/object*, not just *getting values*. thanks for the link! sadly this function isn't standard somewhere in jQuery or so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have Ben Alman's `jQuery BBQ` and a `jQuery.deparam` in it. It is described as `The opposite of jQuery.param, pretty much.`

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/

First example is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 15):

Actually the above answer by @talsibony doesn't take into account query string arrays (such as `test=1&test=2&test=3&check=wow&such=doge`). This is my implementation:

```
function queryStringToJSON(qs) {
    qs = qs || location.search.slice(1);

    var pairs = qs.split('&');
    var result = {};
    pairs.forEach(function(p) {
        var pair = p.split('=');
        var key = pair[0];
        var value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');

        if( result[key] ) {
            if( Object.prototype.toString.call( result[key] ) === '[object Array]' ) {
                result[key].push( value );
            } else {
                result[key] = [ result[key], value ];
            }
        } else {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    });

    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
};
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I love that it creates arrays out of multiple select checkboxes.

Comment: Good answer but i think its better with   if (key !== "") on top of your if statements

Comment: If & is there in value then it is not working. Any solution for it? test=1&test=2&2&test=3&check=wow&such=doge

Comment: What is the situation where there is an actual ampersand in a query string? Won't any ampersands in a URL be encoded as `%26`?

Comment: Five years later, this answer still came in handy. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

I am posting here my function just in case other will look and will want to get it straight forward no need for jquery native JS. Because I was looking for the same thing and finally made this function after viewing others answers:

```
function queryStringToJSON(queryString) {
  if(queryString.indexOf('?') > -1){
    queryString = queryString.split('?')[1];
  }
  var pairs = queryString.split('&');
  var result = {};
  pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
    pair = pair.split('=');
    result[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
  });
  return result;
}


console.log(queryStringToJSON(window.location.href)); 
console.log(queryStringToJSON('test=1&check=wow'));//Object {test: "1", check: "wow"}
```

Comment: If & is there in value then it is not working. Any solution for it? test=1&test=2&2&test=3&check=wow&such=doge

Comment: if its there I think it needs to be url encoded like below:
queryStringToJSON('test6=1&test3=2%262&test1=3&check=wow&such=doge')

Answer (score 8):

In modern browsers, you can also use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) which makes this even easier.

```js
function queryStringToObject(queryString) {
  const pairs = queryString.substring(1).split('&');
  // → ["foo=bar", "baz=buzz"]

  var array = pairs.map((el) => {
    const parts = el.split('=');
    return parts;
  });
  // → [["foo", "bar"], ["baz", "buzz"]]

  return Object.fromEntries(array);
  // → { "foo": "bar", "baz": "buzz" }
}

console.log(queryStringToObject('?foo=bar&baz=buzz'));
```

---

The [URLSearchParams interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) can Interactive with the browsers URL search parameters.
The browser support for [URLSearchParams](https://caniuse.com/?search=URLSearchParams()) is pretty decent.

For your case, it would be:

```js
console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams('foo=bar&baz=buzz'))
);
```

Answer (score 2):

for simple and flat query strings, something like this will do the trick

```
const queryStringToObject = (queryString) => {
  let obj = {}
  if(queryString) {
    queryString.slice(1).split('&').map((item) => {
      const [ k, v ] = item.split('=')
      v ? obj[k] = v : null
    })
  }
  return obj
}
```

```
> queryStringToObject('?foo=bar&baz=buzz')
{ foo: 'bar', baz: 'buzz' }
```

Comment: It deletes the first character for query strings like `data=thisisatestdata`

Comment: you'd want to remove the call to `slice` if you are including the question mark, or consider extending the method to support both string types

Comment: also if there are empty values in query strings then it just removes the key from the object, it should be empty strings instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `URLSearchParams()` constructor creates and returns a new [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object.

```js
var url = new URL('https://example.com?foo=1&bar=2'); 
var params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a bit old - but this is what worked for me - hopefully it will help someone else too ..

```js
var _searchModel = yourquerystring.split("&");
for (var x = 0; x < _searchModel.length; x++) {
  //break each set into key and value pair
  var _kv = _searchModel[x].split("=");

  //console.log(_kv);

  var _fieldID = _kv[0];
  var _fieldVal = _kv[1];
}
```

Comment: Snippet now working as expected, it has error `ReferenceError: yourquerystring is not defined`