# Multiple params with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use React 15.0.2 and React Router 2.4.0.
I want to pass multiple params to my route and I'm not sure how to do it in the best way:

```
<Route name="User" path="/user" component={UserPage}>   
    <Route name="addTaskModal" path="/user/manage:id" component={ManageTaskPage} />
</Route>
```

And what is want is something like:

```
 <Route name="User" path="/user" component={UserPage}>  
    <Route name="addTaskModal" path="/user/manage:id:type" component={ManageTaskPage} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Maybe like thid `path="/user/manage/:id/:type"` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reply. I was just thinking about that. Didn't take my coffee yet. Need to start my brain.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

As @alexander-t mentioned:

```
path="/user/manage/:id/:type"
```

If you want to keep them optional:

```
path="/user/manage(/:id)(/:type)"
```

---

## React Router v4

React Router v4 is different than v1-v3, and optional path parameters aren't explicitly defined in the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).

Instead, you are instructed to define a path parameter that [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) understands. This allows for much greater flexibility in defining your paths, such as repeating patterns, wildcards, etc. So to define a parameter as optional you add a trailing question-mark (?).

So, to define optional parameters, you can do:

```
path="/user/manage/:pathParam1?/:pathParam2?"
```

i.e.

```
<Route path="/user/manage/:pathParam1?/:pathParam2?" component={MyPage} />
```

Whereas, The mandatory Parameters are still same in V4:

```
path="/user/manage/:id/:type"
```

To access PathParam's value, you can do :

```
this.props.match.params.pathParam1
```

Comment: Just a quick note – in React Router 4, optional params look like this: `/user/manage/:id?/:type?`

Comment: Could you please let me know how to specify the path with multiple named parameters? like these: `/route?param1=val1&param2=val2`

Comment: @rehman_00001 I got the solution to the same problem. [Here it is explained really well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61948784/7579494)

Comment: can I hide the parameter in the address bar? thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
<Route path="/:category/:id" exact component={ItemDetails} />
```

In the component, using `useParams` from `react-router-dom`,

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function ItemDetails(props) {

const {id, category} = useParams();
return (
    <div className="">
        {id}
        {category}
    </div>
)
```

Here is the solution, without `props` and using routing library.

Comment: Using the 'exact' prop on Route component worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
<Route name="User" path="/user" component={UserPage}>  
  <Route name="addTaskModal" path="/user/manage/:id/:type" component={ManageTaskPage} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the optional param fields, for some reason it works fine without the slash before the colon inside the braces (). React-router 2.6x