# Why the React Route with 2 optional params not matching a simple URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

FYI, I am using React Router 5.
I have following dependency in my package.json:

> "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",

[ Question edited with a more simplified example ]

Let me describe the issue I am facing. All the following URLs

```
http://localhost:3001/contact
http://localhost:3001/contact/
http://localhost:3001/contact/john50
```

are matching following route ( with 1 optional param )

```
<Route path="/contact/:name([A-Za-z]+)?" component={Contact} />
```

[JSfiddle for above behaviour.](https://jsfiddle.net/arun7it/2mgy4b3k/)

Then, I have updated the above Route by adding another optional param, age.
It looks like this:

```
<Route path="/contact/:name([A-Za-z]+)?:age(\d{2})?" component={Contact} />
```

Why this new updated route with 2 optional params is matched by this URL :

```
http://localhost:3001/contact/
```

and not by this URL :

```
http://localhost:3001/contact
```

[Jsfiddle for this weird behaviour](https://jsfiddle.net/arun7it/27yupc3k/1/)

Why ? Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap the param along with `/` within the optional regex by wrapping it within `()`

```
<Route path="/about/:param1(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})?/:param2(\.[A-Za-z]+)?" component={About} />
```

Note: Params need to separted by `/` which you don't have. You can have your Route like

```
<Route path="/about/:param1(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})?/:param2(\.[A-Za-z]+)?" component={About} />
```

and then your Navigation links will be

```
const Navigation = () => (
    <ul className="navLinks">
      <li><NavLink  to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/contact/john/50">Working Contact</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/contact/">Contact With Slash</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact Without Slash</NavLink></li>
    </ul>
);
```

**Working demo**

Comment: Hi it doesnt work. I have updated my question with the right jsfiddle examples.

Comment: Updated my answer with a demo

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Putting a / works. I agree. But as of my knowledge, separating 2 params with / is not mandatory as a rule. I did not see any react documentation saying that. Let me know if you see any react docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<Route path="/contact/:name?/:age?" component={Contact} />
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604617/react-router-with-optional-path-parameter/35604855) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696391/multiple-params-with-react-router)

Comment: Hi @ravibagul91 I have added JSfiddle examples. I dont have / between name and age.

Comment: @ArunKandregula If you don't have / between name and age, then you need to manually split it.

Comment: I am already doing that. I am manually splitting using reg exp. Its working fine for the best case. Say /contact/John50. Its happily splitting John and 50. The question is why /contact and /contact/ are behaving differently when dealing with 2 optional params with out /.