# URL change without re rendering in React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on an application where I need to change the url of the page without causing a re-render.

I am making a call to fetch all the pages inside componentDidMount like this

```
componentDidMount() {    
    axios.get('/pages')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          pages: response.data,
          slugs: response.data.pages.map(item => Slug(item.title))
        })
      })
```

Once I have all the pages then I want to show the individual pages.
For eg. in the url it has to be like `/page/1/slug-for-page-1` and `/page/2/slug-for-page-2` based on a state variable `activePageNumber` and the active page content will be displayed. Also the corresponding slug should be there on the url.

I tried adding a callback after setState like below, but it didn't work.

```
() => this.props.history.push({
          pathName: '/page',
          state: {activePageNumber : activePageNumber},
        })
```

I thought of adding a child component to manage the activePageNumber state, but I am not sure if its the best way to do it and whether it'll prevent the re-render.

I can implement it such that each page make a separate request to the backend, but I wish to call it only once, and then update the url based on the active page number.

I am not sure how to implement this in react.

I have the following versions

> "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0"
>
> "react": "^16.8.6"

Comment: What's the URL you fetch the pages in before you switch to "/page/1"?

Comment: It is '/pages'.

Comment: So first you navigate to the "/pages" route and then you navigate to "/page/1" after you fetched the pages? You really should just navigate to "/page/1" and fetch the data from there.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but I am planning on making only 1 api call, so I am fetching all the pages and then navigating to different pages using the data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you define your `/page` route like this:

```
<Route
  path="/page/:number"
  component={({ match }) => (
    <Pages activePageNumber={match.params.number} />
  )}
/>
```

The `Pages` component method `componentDidMount` will be called when you switch from, for example, `/home` to `/page/1`, but will *not* be called when you switch from `/page/1` to `/page/2`, because the DOM elements inside the `/page/:number` Route remain of the same type. I suggest you read React's documentation on [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) for a better explaination.

So you can safely put the call to your `/pages` service inside of the `Pages` component, and then in its render method display the page you need based on the `activePageNumber` prop.

```
class Pages extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pages: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/pages')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          pages: response.data
        })
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { pages } = this.state;
    const { activePageNumber } = this.props;

    return pages ? (
      <Page page={pages[activePageNumber]} />
    ) : (
      <div>loading...</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there is another problem, I have a slug for each page which I am computing from the title of each page coming from the axios response, so the url for each page is like `/page/1/new-game` and also the home page from where I am linking doesn't know about this slug. How should I handle this?

Comment: @ShahrukhMohammad you can change the path prop in the Route with `/page/:number/:title?` to match both `/page/1` and `/page/1/new-game`, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37918462/7052392). From the front page you can link to `/page/1`, and when you get your response from the server in the `setState` callback you can replace that url with `/page/1/title-of-the-page`.

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of `Navigate` from 'react-router-dom'

```html
const navigate = useNavigate();
<Button onClick={() => navigate('/products/addnewproduct')}>
Click Me
</Button>
```