# React: change url without rerender; using window.history?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "settings" page in my react app. The page has several tabs rendering different parts of settings.

It would be better UX if a user can share urls with other users.

What I want is (inside "settings" page):

1. user A clicks a tab
2. **url changes with a `#tabname` appended**
3. user A send that url to user B, and user B open that url
4. user B sees the same tab as user A

But with react router, the whole page re-renders if the url changed:

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"

const MyComp = (props) => {
  ...

  const onTabChange = () => {
    // append #tabname here
    props.history.replace(...); // or `push`
    ...
  }

  ...

export default withRouter(MyComp)
}
```

After a lot of searches, I found a solution to use `window.history`:

```js
  const onTabChange = () => {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, "#tabname");
    ...
  }
```

This does the trick, but little information and explanation, and I'd love to know the consequences of using this trick.

Is this a valid solution (for a react app)? Will this cause any problem?

(PS. I know how to parse a url)

---

**More details**:

To be more specific, there is a `AuthChecker` wrapper for all pages. When react router's `location` changes, it checks for the route's allowed auths and current user's auth.

I've tried `/path/:id` and everything but all change `location`, so auth checked and page rerendered.

And I've given up a solution in react router and **just want to know**: is it safe to change url with `window.history` in a react app using react router to manage routes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL change without re rendering in React router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56053810/url-change-without-re-rendering-in-react-router)

Answer (score 1):

this question is already answerd at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101831/react-router-how-do-i-update-the-url-without-causing-a-navigation-reload).

so it says window has a property called history and there is a method on history which helps you update the history state without react-router-dom understanding it.

like this:

```
window.history.replaceState(null, 'New Page Title', '/new_url');
```