# Cannot see the route params in match.params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Below push will redirect the URL to [http://localhost:3000/search?category=furniture&city=San+Jose%2C+CA%2C+USA](http://localhost:3000/search?category=furniture&city=San%20Jose%2C%20CA%2C%20USA) when I choose the furniture for the category and "San Jose, CA, USA" for the city.

```
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/search',
      search: "?" + new URLSearchParams({category: this.category, city: this.userCity}).toString()
    });
```

In App.jsx, I defined a route like below:

```
<Route path="/search/:category?/:city?" component={props => <EventSearchPage {...props} />}/>
```

In the `EventSearchPage` component, when I tried to access `this.props.match.params`, I see both category and city are `undefined`.

Can someone kindly let me know where went wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out queryString can do the trick to get the URL params like doing below:

```
queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
```

npm package link is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

Answer (score 1):

When adding parameters to routes with react router, you can do it this way so that they are given to the component.

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: `/search/${this.category}/${this.userCity}`,
});
```

The route component would look something like this to receive these parameters.

```
<Route path="/search/:category?/:city?" component={props => <EventSearchPage {...props} />}/>
```

Documentation for react router can be found [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Comment: It's not working. When taking ? off the Route path, it just couldn't find the page and return 404 error.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I didn't realize that including `?` meant it would take the inputs to the route as an optional parameters. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696391/multiple-params-with-react-router) explains more but I think you can keep the `?` if you have a link directed to `http://localhost:3000/search`