# How to Give Dynamic Routing in react js using simple array of object file

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
const userdata = [
{
    id:1,
    name:"kuber",
    phone:"8989"
},
{
    id:2,
    name:"sahil",
    phone:"9696"
}

];
export default userdata
```

From this to>>> `<Route path={"user/:id"} component={user} />`

What code should i use in "User" component if useParams has id=1 then how to show only id 1, name kuber, phone 8989

Comment: if forward object in path when path not friendly and And it is not suitable for SEO

Comment: you should this answer 
[multiple-params-with-react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696391/multiple-params-with-react-router)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest way you can do it like this:

in your **User.js/jsx** import the **userData**.
Then you can get the id from url using `props.match.params.id` and then you can filter from userData from that `props.match.params.id` .
Note: You need to do this inside so every time id changes it gets the user of that id

```
useEffect(()=>{

 // your code here
 
},[props.match]);
```

Comment: thanks for answering this using filter only return one value can you help me out what exactly I code to follow to achieve all elements in id = 1

Comment: if you `let user = userData.filter(user => user.id === props.match.params.id);` The user object contains all the data for user with id 1

Comment: My bro work well thanks a lot for this dynamic routing works `useEffect(()=>{
    let user = userdata.filter(user => user.id == id);
    setnam(user)
    console.log(id)
    console.log(user)
},[id])

    return(
        
    <>
        <div className="p-3">
            <h2>Description</h2>
            {nam.map(myuser=>(
                <li>{myuser.name}</li>
            ))}    
             

        </div>  
    </>
)`