# How to convert string to array of data and send in ajax post request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have

```
var data = decodeURIComponent($(this).attr("name"));
```

output of var data is

```
ldef_index[]=5&lquality[]=0&id[]=&rdef_index[]=315&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=7115&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=50&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=55&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=5086&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=711&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=3229&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=7555&rquality[]=0&tslt=c9942&notes=test
```

How can i convert this variable to send it as data in jquery ajax request ?

```
  $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : 'https://example.com/ajax/test.php',
        data: { ldef_index[]: 5,
                lquality[]: 0,
                id[]= ,
                rdef_index[]: 315,
                rquality[]: 0,
                rdef_index[]: 7115,
                rquality[]: 0,
                rdef_index[]: 50,
                rquality[]: 0,
                rdef_index[]: 55,
                rquality[]: 0,
                rdef_index[]: 5086,
                rquality[]: 0,
                rdef_index[]: 711,
                rquality[]: 0,
                rdef_index[]: 3229,
                rquality[]: 0,
                rdef_index[]: 7555,
                rquality[]: 0,
                tslt: c9942,
                notes: test },
        });
```

Comment: Assuming it's a string, `data: data` will do it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan already tryed but it post it as data : ldef_index[]=5&lquality[]=0&id[]=&rdef_index[]=315&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=7115&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=50&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=55&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=5086&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=711&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=3229&rquality[]=0&rdef_index[]=7555&rquality[]=0&tslt=c9942&notes=test

Comment: Exactly, that's what you asked for...?

Comment: If you're trying to build an object, split by ',', replace = with : (better yet, do that in reverse).

Comment: take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557526/deserialize-query-string-to-json-object

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want parameters to look like this http://prntscr.com/dy5pzq , and when i send it as data: data it looks like this : http://prntscr.com/dy5rr2 .

Comment: what does `$(this).attr("name")` return ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Actually u were right , i was just sending it in wrong format . Sorry This is solved now. If i send data: data it do just what i want